# SQL: Only Rounded numbers shown, everything else: Useless

Tags: sql, numbers, rounding, division

I'm currently having terrible Problems with SQL,
I am trying to calculate certain values, similiar to the ex. below:

```
SELECT Sum(OrdersAchieved)/ Sum(SaleOpportunities) as CalculatedValue
FROM (
        SELECT Count(OT.SalesOpportunity) AS SaleOpportunities
               Count(VK.Orders) AS OrdersAchieved
        FROM fact_VertriebKalkulation VK
     ) AS A
```

Sadly every number that takes place in the calculation, is only shown as the last rounded number!
say: 3/4 gives me 0, and 4/4 = 1, 8/4 = 2, and so on.
While trying to find out what the Problem could be, i found that even the following seems to do the same Thing!

```
select 2/7 as Value
```

Gives Out = 0!!!
so i tried this

```
select convert(float,2/7) as  Value
```

and it's the same Thing!
What can i do, has anybody ever seen something like this?
or does somebody know the Answer to my Question?
Thanks a lot for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 2/7 as Value
```

...using two integers means integer division, which is correct as 0.

```
select 2.0/7 as Value
```

...using at least one floating point type gives 0.285714 which is what you seem to be looking for.

In other words, cast either of the operands to float, and the division will give the result you want;

```
select convert(float,2)/7 as  Value
```

If you cast after the division is already done as an integer division, you'll only be casting the resulting 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert both values before dividing

```
select convert(float,2)/convert(float,7) as  Value
```

or one of them

```
select convert(float,2)/7 as  Value

select 2/convert(float,7) as  Value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
select convert(float,2)/7 as  Value
```

OR this

```
select 2/convert(float,7) as  Value
```

Answer (score 1):

**Sorry, I can't show you SQLFiddel Demo**

**[This is the link where I tried your problem](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_basics)**. You can paste below query in the Textarea of any Question and get solution online or paste it in your SQL Editor window.

**Below is the sample query which you can try :**

```
SELECT convert(float,convert(float,2)/convert(float,7,4),1) as ans
```